# Django Token objects update error : django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: authtoken_token.user_id

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, put, django-viewsets

I was using django user class and rest_framework Token class to store the user info and the token. For the same I was using `serializers.ModelSerializer` class. But when I am making update request(check update method) to update the user info as well as the token that I have, its giving me error.

Here is **serializers.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework.authtoken.views import Token

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['id', 'username', 'password']

        extra_kwargs = {
            'password' : {
                'write_only':True,
                'required': True
            }
        }
    
    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User.objects.create_user(**validated_data)
        Token.objects.create(user=user) # create token for the user
        return user

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.username = validated_data['username']
        instance.set_password(validated_data['password'])
        instance.save()
        Token.objects.update(user=instance)

        return instance
```

**views.py**

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated, IsOwnerOfObject]
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path, include
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register('users', UserViewSet, basename = 'users')

urlpatterns = [
    path('api/', include(router.urls)),
]
```

**Error :**

> django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed:
> authtoken_token.user_id

This is how I am making the request with the authorisation token in the header field:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is invalid:

```
Token.objects.update(user=instance)
```

Here, you are trying to update a Token object without specifying which one. You should do `.filter()` or `.get()` before updating.

But that statement is reduntant. Think about it, you're updating the token from 'instance' to 'instance'. So, everything will be the same. Try deleting it as it doesn't have any effect.

Comment: Token is generated on the password field right! so when I updated the password shouldn't the token also change

Comment: Also what do you mean by  `updating the token from 'instance' to 'instance'.`

Comment: @HimanshuPoddar I mean that the instance didn't change. You updated its username and password, but the ID remains the same, so the statement has no effect.

Comment: As far as I understood, that you want to update the token for the user on PUT. To achieve that, you will have to create a new token, and not update it. You are doing it the opposite way. You are trying to set the token to a different user, while what you should do is to create a new token and assign it to the same user.

Comment: so create and assign in update function like this only right `Token.objects.create(user=user)`

Comment: Yes, exactly! Give it a try and let me know if it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

What do you want to achieve?

```
Token.objects.update(user=instance)
```

It doesn't make any sense. It is update without WHERE clause.

I think that you "want" to do something like this.

```
Token.objects.filter(user=instance).update(user=instance)
```

That query does nothing really.

I think that you really want is token invalidation. You must delete the current one and generate new.

Comment: I don't know but I still don't see the new token being updated in the admin panel

Comment: Token is generated on the password field right! so when I updated the password shouldn't the token also change